# A java console program that converts "BINARY" to "DECIMAL" without using a predefined method using for loop

Tags: java, binary, console, decimal

I made a java console program that prints the decimal value of the binary value inputted. Now, I have a problem with my program that

for e.g. output:
Enter input = 10011101 then the binary value is 3534200 instead of 157

After surfing the internet for the formula in converting binary value to decimal, this is the reference I took for making this program.

1*2^7 + 0*2^6 + 0*2^5 + 1*2^4 + 1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 = 157.

I tried the long version in making this program, in using for loop... I guess that's a dumb challenge? haha!

here's the code(w/ comments!):

```
byte binary[] = new byte[127];   //declared a byte array for input value
int power = 2, formula = 0;      //declared the power and the formula as int
System.out.print("Enter Binary: "); //prints "Enter binary:"
System.in.read(binary);          //inserts the input in the binary array
Integer bin = Integer.parseInt(new String(binary).trim()); //converts the input value to int for another conversion
String b = Integer.toString(bin); //converts the int bin to string
Integer num = Integer.parseInt(new String(b.substring(b.length() - 1).trim())); 
//num variable gets the value of last string (should be anyway)
System.out.println("The Decimal Value of " + bin + " is ");
for(int i = b.length(); i > 0; i--){ 
    for(int a = i; a > 0; a--){ //the condition
        power = power*2;        //as the loop goes, if 2^3 then it should be 8
    }
    formula = formula + (num * (power)); //as the given formula above, this is what I did
    System.out.println("power: " + power);//if you want reference, I left it here
    System.out.println("formula: " +formula);
    System.out.println("num: " + num);

    num = Integer.parseInt(new String(b.substring(i - 1).trim())); //uhm dunno how to describe this, but you'll see
    power = 2;
}
System.out.print(formula);
```

}
}

ever since I started using java, this is the only thing that I know. (refer to my last question since sep 4)

please help :(

Comment: You probably want to reset `power` to 1 before your `for (int a` loop. Or just use `1 << i`.

Comment: wait, I'll check...

Comment: Please, do not re-ask the same questions. Edit the original if you need to add complementary information.

Comment: i did not duplicate this is my own code, the first one i did was decimal to binary, and this one is binary to decimal. @tunaki

Comment: what did I do wrong ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems:

1) `Integer.parseInt(new String(binary).trim())` does not do what you think it does. Therefore, your num is wrong.

2) You calculate your power wrong.

3) A general advice, put some empty lines to separate your code into small blocks that make sense. It will be easier on the eyes.

The fixed program should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte binary[] = new byte[127];   //declared a byte array for input value
    int power = 2, formula = 0;      //declared the power and the formula as int

    System.out.print("Enter Binary: "); //prints "Enter binary:"
    System.in.read(binary);          //inserts the input in the binary array
    Integer bin = Integer.parseInt(new String(binary).trim()); //converts the input value to int for another conversion

    String b = Integer.toString(bin); //converts the int bin to string
    Integer num; //num variable gets the value of last string (should be anyway)
    System.out.println("The Decimal Value of " + bin + " is ");

    for(int i = b.length(); i > 0; i--){ 
        power = 1;
        num = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(b.charAt(i-1)));

        for(int a = i; a < b.length(); a++){ //the condition
            power = power*2;        //as the loop goes, if 2^3 then it should be 8
        }

        formula = formula + (num * (power)); //as the given formula above, this is what I did
        System.out.println("power: " + power);//if you want reference, I left it here
        System.out.println("formula: " +formula);
        System.out.println("num: " + num);
    }
    System.out.print(formula);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using `bin` and `b` here? Why not just take the input as a String and parse it? Isn't this unnecessarily long?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just wanted to make as little changes in the code as possible to show the errors without perplexing him/her by rewriting the code. If I go down that route, there are even more things I would change.

Comment: Yeah, because at first look of his code, I was very confused as to why he's using a `byte` array if in the end it's going to be converted and useless anyway.